# Entity Framework query - return unique values from child table

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, unique

I have Entity Framework model as below and data in the corresponding database tables:

[image: Entity Model]

**Question:** How do I effectively query the model to return unique sales_type entities for a given person? (person_sales table is very large, ~ 1BN rows, other tables relatively small)

**Example:** I want to know all unique sales_types for a person "John". The answer here would return 3 unique items: "Internal", "External" and "Mixed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defintely will need index on `person_id` column for `person_sales` table. And query will look this way

```
var salesTypes = (from p in db.person
                  join ps in db.person_sales on p.id equals ps.person_id
                  join sm in db.sales_mapping on ps.sales_mapping_id equals sm.id
                  join st in db.sales_types on sm.sales_type_id equals st.id
                  where p.name == "John"
                  select st.sales_name).Distinct();
```

Generated SQL will look like:

```
SELECT
    [Distinct1].[sales_name] AS [sales_name]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT [Extent4].[sales_name] AS [sales_name]
           FROM  [dbo].[person] AS [Extent1]
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[person_sales] AS [Extent2] 
                 ON [Extent1].[id] = [Extent2].[person_id]
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[sales_mapping] AS [Extent3] 
                 ON [Extent2].[sales_mapping_id] = [Extent3].[id]
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[sales_types] AS [Extent4] 
                 ON [Extent3].[sales_type_id] = [Extent4].[id]
           WHERE N'John' = [Extent1].[name]
    )  AS [Distinct1]
```

Comment: That works. If I need to select the whole row in sales_type table instead of only sales_name column, how would I do that ? (Distinction still be based on the column sales_name)

Comment: @user2143213 which `id` you need if there is several sales_types with same name? Also what is expected count of returned non-distinct sales types?

Comment: Good question: let's say the distinction should be based on the column id (=primary key)

Comment: @user2143213 sorry, didn't get you. Primary keys are distinct. What do you mean by distinctiona based on id?

Comment: In short, how do I get the first 3 rows from the table "sales_type" for the person "John"? Your initial answer works ok, but it only selects data from one column

Comment: @user2143213 it's simple - you should select full `st` entity and take required number of entities: `select st).Take(3)`

Comment: If I select full st I will get error "Specified cast is not valid" var salesTypes = (from p in db.person
                  join ps in db.person_sales on p.id equals ps.person_id
                  join sm in db.sales_mapping on ps.sales_mapping_id equals sm.id
                  join st in db.sales_types on sm.sales_type_id equals st.id
                  where p.name == "John"
                  select st).Distinct();

Comment: @user2143213 maybe you have this error elsewhere? I don't see any casting here. How do you use `salesTypes` variable?

Comment: I posted new question (easier to explain there). Could you take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877293/entity-framework-query-return-unique-rows-from-child-table