# Entity Framework query - return unique rows from child table

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, distinct

I have Entity Framework model as below and data in the corresponding database tables:

[image]

**Question:** How do I query the model for returning all the rows (full entities, not anonymous type) from `sales_type` relevant to a given `person` ?

If the data is as above, then for John, the query should return first three rows from `sales_type`-table and for Mark it should return the rows 2 and 5.

Comment: are you looking for long single row for each record?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
ctx.PersonSales
   .Where(ps=> ps.Person.Id = myPersonId)
   .Where(ps=> ps.SalesMapping != null && ps.SalesMapping.SalesType != null)
   .Select(ps=>ps.SalesMapping.SalesType)
   .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var personId=1;
var result= (
        from salesType in db.sales_type
        where
            (
                from salesMapping in db.sales_mapping
                join personSale in db.person_Sales
                    on salesMapping.id equals personSale.sales_mapping_id
                join person in db.person
                    on personSale.person_id equals person.id
                where
                    person.Id == personId
                select salesMapping.sales_type_id
            ).Contains(salesType.id)
        select salesType
    ).ToList();
```

Where db is the linq data context